# Converting to natural mathematical typography

Tags: traditional-form

I'd like to convert

```
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalB]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y, z, t]
```

into the following display typography

$$\frac{\partial^2 {\cal B}(x,y,z,t)}{\partial z^2}$$

Alas, `StandardForm`, `InputForm`, `TraditionalForm`, `DisplayForm`, ... don't work.

Comment: If you expect a more "general" solution, then it would be helpful to add some more concrete examples in your question because "natural mathematical typography" is a very vague description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r = \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalB]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y, z, t]
```

Now

```
pdConv[f_] := 
 TraditionalForm[
  f /. Derivative[inds__][g_][vars__] :> 
    Apply[Defer[D[g[vars], ##]] &, 
     Transpose[{{vars}, {inds}}] /. {{var_, 0} :> 
        Sequence[], {var_, 1} :> {var}}]]
pdConv[r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thanks to [mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting](https://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/15/mathematica-qa-series-converting-to-conventional-mathematical-typesetting/) by Vitaliy Kaurov

---

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great... thanks ($+1$).  I was hoping for a more general solution, rather than one so tailored to my specific case.  Let's see if one arises before I accept this.  Thanks again.

Comment: Good enough ($\checkmark$)... thanks!